# Generating table row based on focus to a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a table in my html page where each cell has a form field corresponding to the title. Initially I have two rows as shown in the image below.

[image: form table]

I have written a jquery function that should generate an extra row on click of the first form element in in the last row. The function is given below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 2;
$("#s_prd" + i).click(function() {
                $("#fm_orditms").append(
                        '<tr>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <select id="s_prd' + (i + 1) + '" class="form-control" name="prdId[]">\n\
                                <option>Select</option>\n\
                            </select>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        \n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <select id="s_ccon' + (i + 1) + '" class="form-control" name="cconId[]">\n\
                                <option>Select</option>\n\
                            </select>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <input type="number" name="qty[]" class="form-control" id="qty' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 120px;"/>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <input type="date" name="ordDate[]" class="form-control" id="ordDate' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 145px;"/>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <input type="date" name="bilDate[]" class="form-control" id="bilDate' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 145px;"/>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <input type="date" name="dlvDate[]" class="form-control" id="dlvDate' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 145px;"/>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <select id="s_mdt' + (i + 1) + '" class="form-control" name="mdt[]" style="width: 120px;">\n\
                                <option>Select</option>\n\
                                <option value="air">Air</option>\n\
                                <option value="digital">Digital</option>\n\
                                <option value="hand">Hand</option>\n\
                                <option value="road">Road</option>\n\
                                <option value="sea">Sea</option>\n\
                            </select>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        '
                        );
                i++;
            });
});
```

Since the initial value of i=2, the generation of the row only happens when I click on the second row. I want it to be in such a way that every time I click on the first first field of the last row in the table an additional row is generated. Please tell me how to achieve this particular feature.

Comment: I would suggest using jquery plugin for creating the tables. Try https://www.datatables.net

Comment: use css class and apply click event with jQuery delegated event

Comment: @Venkata wont the additional row be created on click of any of the boxes with that particular class name.

Comment: I added answer, with the concept of [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), observe the behavior and learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $ordTable = $("#fm_orditms");
  $ordTable.on("click", "tr:last :input:first", function() {
    var i = $("tr", $ordTable).length;
    $ordTable.append(
                    '<tr>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <select id="s_prd' + (i + 1) + '" class="form-control" name="prdId[]">\n\
                                <option>Select</option>\n\
                            </select>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        \n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <select id="s_ccon' + (i + 1) + '" class="form-control" name="cconId[]">\n\
                                <option>Select</option>\n\
                            </select>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <input type="number" name="qty[]" class="form-control" id="qty' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 120px;"/>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <input type="date" name="ordDate[]" class="form-control" id="ordDate' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 145px;"/>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <input type="date" name="bilDate[]" class="form-control" id="bilDate' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 145px;"/>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <input type="date" name="dlvDate[]" class="form-control" id="dlvDate' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 145px;"/>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <select id="s_mdt' + (i + 1) + '" class="form-control" name="mdt[]" style="width: 120px;">\n\
                                <option>Select</option>\n\
                                <option value="air">Air</option>\n\
                                <option value="digital">Digital</option>\n\
                                <option value="hand">Hand</option>\n\
                                <option value="road">Road</option>\n\
                                <option value="sea">Sea</option>\n\
                            </select>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                    </tr>\n\
                        '
    );
    i++;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

like..

```
function runAfterInsertAndOnStart() {    
    $('select.form-control').unbind('click');
    var i = $("#fm_orditms").find('tr').length
    $("#s_prd" + i).click(function(){
       [...]
    });
}
```

important is the first id of your row... if you start with 0 than its ok,, start with 1, you need to add 1 to `i`

so this will bin the click on the first select in the last row of your table... but you need to call the function again if you added a new row, to calc the new last row

Comment: right after the row is added.
You can create a new Function and call it after your insertion or place the recall right in your function: `$("#s_prd" + i).click(function(){[...] ; runAfterInsertAndOnStart();});`

Comment: This is one of the approach +1 to you mate

Comment: It will hurt my pride, but im happy, that even you see what im doing